# How to select Multiple checkboxs values and Post to the server on Form Submission using React-Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have form and I need to select multiple checkboxes and send those checkbox values to the server on Form submission..I tried but Unable to get those checkbox values, In the State I took as any array("checking" :[]) because I need to push multiple values...
Here is my code, Please can anyone help me out in this? Thanks in Advance

```
   const [data, setdata] = useState({
            "UserName" : "",
            "PhoneNumber" : "",
             "email" : "",
              "dropDown" :"",
              "gender" : null,
              "checking" :[],
        })
    
    const handleChnage=(e)=>{
        if(e.target.name !=="checking"){
        setdata({...data,[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
        } else if(e.target.name ==="checking"){
            setdata({...data,[e.target.name]:e.target.checked});
        }
       }
    
  <div className="mb-3">
                                                <label className="mb-2 fw-bold">Checkbox Value</label>
                                                <div className="form-check">
                                                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checking" id="Javascript" value={data.checking} onChange={handleChnage} value="" />
                                                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckDefault">Javascript</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="form-check">
                                                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checking" id="React JS" value={data.checking} onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckChecked">React JS</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="form-check">
                                                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checking" id="HTML" value={data.checking} onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckChecked">HTML</label>
                                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the Updated handleChange Function, then It will Work Fine

```
const handleChnage = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name !== "checking") {
        setdata({ ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    } else if (e.target.name === "checking") {
      
            let value = e.target.value;
            //console.log(value);
            let newcheckes = { ...data };
              //console.log(newcheckes);
              //newcheckes.checking.push(value);
                  //console.log(data);
            if(newcheckes.checking.indexOf(value) === -1){
                  newcheckes.checking.push(value);
            }else {
                newcheckes.checking.splice(newcheckes.checking.indexOf(value),1);
            }
            console.log(newcheckes);

    }
}
```